# On integer values which are attained by $n/\pi(n)$ only once

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $\pi (n)$ denote the prime counting function. I can prove that $\mathbb N \setminus \{1\} \subseteq \{n/ \pi(n) : n \in \mathbb N \}$ . Now for every integer $m>1$ , define $s(m) := \{ n \in \mathbb N : n>1 , n/ \pi(n)=m \}$ . Does there exist any integer $m$ such that $|s(m)|=1$ ? If there exists such integers , then are there infinitely many of them ?

Comment: Seems that $\frac{n}{\pi(n)}=11$ only holds for $n=175197$

Comment: How did you prove that $\frac{n}{\pi(n)}=k$ has a solution for every integer $k>1$ ?

Comment: The values $2,3,4,\cdots ,17$ except $11$ appear more than once.

Comment: $18$ and $19$ appear more than once as well.

Comment: @Peter : here's a general way to see how every integer more than 1 is attained : Let $f :\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ be a function such that the sequence $\{n/f(n)\}$ is unbounded . If $x,n $ be positive integers such that $x/f(x) \le n $ , then $y/f(y)=n$ , where either $y=x$, or if $x/f(x)\ne n $, then we can take $y=max \{w \in \mathbb N : x \le w < z , w/f(w) <n \} $ , where $z/f(z) >n$ (such positive integer $z$ exist as the sequence $\{ m/f(m) \}$ is unbounded ) . For our case, note that $2/\pi(2) \le n$ for every integer $n>1$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} n/\pi(n)=\infty $

Comment: @Peter : in the above comment , one more property of $f$ has to be assumed which I forgot to mention , $f$ has to be non-decreasing

Comment: @Peter : Just work out the proof, if you can prove it , then it is correct ...

Comment: What does mean $|s(m)|$? Is it the cardinal of $s(m)$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, misao. I was wrong misunderstanding your question. Regards.

Comment: @Piquito : no problem ... I am happy to see that my problem has gained attention ..

Comment: @Peter: Note that the Rosser–Schoenfeld bound $\pi(x) < \frac x{\log x}\big( 1 + \frac{3}{2\log x} \big)$ shows that $\frac n{\pi(n)} > 11$ for $n \ge 230000$.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but a table showing the frequences using the primes upto $10^{10}$. The first column is the value of $\large \frac{n}{\pi(n)}$ and the second column shows how often it appeared :

```
2   4
3   3
4   3
5   6
6   7
7   6
8   6
9   3
10   9
11   1
12   18
13   11
14   12
15   21
16   3
17   10
18   33
19   31
20   32
21   24
```

Apparently, the frequences do not strictly increase. Value $16$ is particular suprising. It appeared only $3$ times. In total, only $243$ times, an integer-value appears.

UPDATE : You are right, misao. I didn't understand the argument, but finally I could prove your claim. Sorry for my doubt ...

Moreover, the following can also be proven : If $k>2$ and $f(p)<k$, then there exists $N>p$ with $f(N)=k$. This implies misao's claim.

Proof : Suppose , $q>p$ is the smallest number with $f(q)\ge k$. If $f(q)=k$, we are done. Otherwise, we have $p<\pi(p)\cdot k\le \pi(q)\cdot k<q$. If there is no prime $P$ with $p<P<q$, then we can choose $N:=\pi(p)\cdot k$ and we have $\frac{N}{\pi(N)}=\frac{N}{\pi(p)}=k$. If there is at least a prime $P$ with $p<P<q$, assume $P$ is the largest of those. Now, we have either $f(P)=k$ and are done, or we have $P<\pi(P)\cdot k\le \pi(q)\cdot k<q$ and $N:=\pi(P)\cdot k$ does the job.

So, if $s$ is the smallest number with $f(s)=k$ ($k>2$), then there is another number $t$ with $f(t)=k$, if and only if for some positive integer $m$, the interval $[s,s+mk]$ contains at least $m$ primes.

Comment: Since $n/\pi(n) >11$ for $n>230000$ (as Greg Martin remarked) and you have checked upto $10^{10}>230000$ that $11$ appears only  once , so $11$ appears only once for all integer values. Thus we atleast now know that $|s(11)|=1$

Comment: With the help of Wolfram alpha, I could extend to $26$. All values from $2$ to $26$, except $11$, appear at least twice.

Comment: And finally, with the $n$-th prime page, I found out that $27$ appears at least twice.